# variable inside addEventListener is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Inside an upload script I would like to check the dimensions of the image. if these are to small, it shouldn't show the preview-image. Unfortunately the vars are not working.

Can anyone help me so that the variable var_error have the value 1 if pic_width is lower than 720.

Thanks

```
var fileInput   = document.querySelector('#file');
var preview     = document.getElementById('preview');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
var var_error = 0;

preview.onload = function() {
    var pic_width = this.naturalWidth; 
    var pic_height = this.naturalHeight;

    if(pic_width < 720) {
        $('.contest_upload_error').fadeIn();
        $('.contest_upload_error').replaceWith('Falsche Bildgrösse (Mindestgrösse 1080px x 720px)');
        document.var_error = 1;
    }

    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
};

if(var_error == 0) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    preview.setAttribute('src', url);
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Why are you setting `document.var_error`? You can’t make an `if` check before the image has finished loading.

Comment: thanks ok but how? or how can I stop loading?

Comment: Just put the `if` inside the `onload` function. If it’s outside it’s going to execute immediately after the `onload` function is set. Setting the `onload` function doesn’t mean _waiting_ for it. Research asynchronicity and events in JavaScript.

Comment: I tried with var_error = 1; but not working, same as document.var_error..

Comment: tried to put the if(var_error == 0)... //include preview.setAtt.. inside the onLoad, but then no preview

Comment: if onLoad is mentioned that it is to small, the preview should not appears, if it's ok it should show the preview.

Comment: Oh the wonders of asynchronous logic. (your if statement runs long before the onload does)

Comment: @KevinB yeah, but any solution or help? thanks

Comment: Move it to inside the onload.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the following may work better for you.

```
var fileInput = document.querySelector('#file');
var preview = document.getElementById('preview');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var e = event;
    preview.onload = function() {
        var pic_width = this.naturalWidth,
            pic_height = this.naturalHeight;

        if (pic_width < 720) {
            $('.contest_upload_error')
                .fadeIn();
                .replaceWith('Falsche Bildgrösse (Mindestgrösse 1080px x 720px)');
            this.setAttribute('src', URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
        }

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
    };
});
```

**Notes:**

1. I saved the `change` event handler's parameter, `event`, as `var e`, so we can use it in the next function.
2. I moved the `if(var_error == 0)` part to inside the `load` event handler. Where it was situated originally was wrong, as `preview.onload()` is asynchronous and will be called after `if(var_error==0)`, so `var_error`, at that point in the script, remains `0`.
3. I removed the variable `var_error` as we now do the error checking inside `preview.onload()`'s `if(pic_width < 720)` conditional statement instead.

**Additional notes:**

You have a strange mix of jQuery and Javascript selectors in there. At the top you select elements using Javascript and inside the `change` event handler you select elements with jQuery.